# Powershell, function add trailing space while concatenating string (parameters)

Tags: string, function, powershell

here's my issue :

```
function Dummy ($path1, $fileName1) {
    Write-Host "$path1$fileName1"
}

Dummy 'folder\', 'test2.exe'
```

result is :

```
folder\ test2.exe
```

I have just no idea why this whitespace is added. 
I tried different formatting option (trim, string formatting, even native .net one without result).

Regex kind of work as a "post issue" but is too extrem fo my usage (folder with whitespace in name)

Note that those option i tried work perfectly (or should i say "as expected" -_-') OUT of the function.

if anyone could tell me how dumb i am i'd be glad -_-'

NB : i keep adding a simple "hi" first line of this thread, it just get removed everytime so, sorry for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are not sending in two parameters even though it might look that way. When you use a comma you are actually sending in an array. So `$path` will be an array with the values `'folder\'` and `'test2.exe'`. And of course `$fileName1` will be empty.

So when you convert `$path` to a string the values will be separated by a space.

Remove the comma from the call and it will work:

```bsh
Dummy 'folder\' 'test2.exe'
```

As a sidenote: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. But if you want to create paths I would recommend using:

```bsh
Join-Path "folder" "test2.exe"
```

Comment: well that was quick, and ... ty ! sidenote : tried the join-path way before posting here, but thanks to this array issue, i had the same kind of issue there. and i got you point about this :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:

```
function Dummy ($path1, $fileName1) {
    Write-Host "$($path1)$($fileName1)"
}

Dummy 'folder\', 'test2.exe'
```

Comment: Not working unfortunely, @Ostemar got it right thought !